# Vuforia + Three.js

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl, vuforia

I'm facing an issue integrating three.js and Vuforia and I really don't know how to solve this cause I really don't know anything about OpenGl.

We are developing a small AR app and we would like to do that using Vuforia for tracking and recognition and three.js for rendering.

We placed a Vuforia view which render the camera and get the target info, on top of that we placed a WkWebView to render the augmentations using three.js.

We already set up a communication channel between the views and we send target position matrix and camera info from Vuforia to three.js.

What we are unable to do is to correctly make use of that information in three.js  and align models position to target position.

From Vuforia we grab modelViewMatrix, modelViewProjection.

Any help we'll be really appreciated!!!

Comment: You can try the ARgon browser. It is still in beta but it already uses Vuforia + three.js http://argonjs.io/argon-tutorials/tutorials/vuforia.html

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you can not do both things a the same time in a web browser (i.e. chrome), last year I tried several days what you say, using opencv + three.js.
In case of emergency for a client, you can use 2d sprite animations instead of 3d rendering